# Distinct Count without using CALCULATE

Tags: dax

I've come across this `DAX` measure:

```
# CustMultProds = 
COUNTROWS( 
    FILTER(
        Customer,
        CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT( Sales[ProductKey] ) ) >= 2
    ) 
)
```

I pretty much understand how it works - it iterates over `Customer` inside the `FILTER` function, then the row context created by this iterator is transitioned into a filter context so that it is able to get the number of distinct products from the `Sales` table.

I am wondering is it possible to re-write the measure without using `CALCULATE` ? I got as far as using `RELATEDTABLE` but then not sure how to extract the distinct ProductKeys from each related table:

```
# CustMultProds = 
COUNTROWS( 
    FILTER(
        Customer,
        RELATEDTABLE (Sales) 
        ...
        ...
    ) 
)
```

Comment: beware: RELATEDTABLE() performs a context transition https://dax.guide/relatedtable/

Comment: @sergiom thanks for this extra information - the focus for me is just an alternative without calculate - I've altered the post's title to not include context transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible implementation of the measure using `RELATEDTABLE`. But Context Transition still happens once per customer because `RELATEDTABLE` performs a context transition

```
# CustMultProds =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        Customer,
        VAR CustomerSales =
            RELATEDTABLE( Sales )
        RETURN
            MAXX( CustomerSales, Sales[ProductKey] )
                <> MINX( CustomerSales, Sales[ProductKey] )
    )
)
```

This is another way to write a measure leveraging RELATEDTABLE, that could be modified to deal with a different number of distinct products

```
# CustMultProds =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        Customer,
        COUNTROWS( SUMMARIZE( RELATEDTABLE( Sales ), Sales[ProductKey] ) ) >= 2
    )
)
```

Comment: option 2 is very close to the direction I was heading - thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is another possible implementation, without `CALCULATE` and `RELATEDTABLE`.
But it scans the entire Sales table once per customer, so, even if it doesn't perform a context transition I'd expect it to be slower

```
# CustMultProds =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        Customer,
        VAR SalesProducts =
            SUMMARIZE( Sales, Sales[CustomerKey], Sales[ProductKey] )
        RETURN
            COUNTROWS(
                FILTER( SalesProduct, Sales[CustomerKey] = Customer[CustomerKey] )
            ) >= 2
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
# CustMultProds alternative = 
VAR sales_product_count_per_customer =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        VALUES(Sales[CustomerKey]),
        "ProductCount", DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(Sales[ProductKey])    
    )
VAR _result =
    SUMX(
        sales_product_count_per_customer,
        IF( [ProductCount] >= 2, 1)
    )
RETURN _result
```